# How to write correct CSS in item.add_css() when you use FOR loop?

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm learning Scrapy and trying to populate my item with add_css(). 
I scrape https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/casas-venta-capital-federal.html
I want to scrape some info about each house. So I using FOR loop to iterate through the list houses (div.posting-card).
I would like to populate my item with add_css(), but I don't know how to use CSS in that case?

To make it clear.

This is that I'd done before without add_css:

```
        for casa in response.css('div.posting-card'):
            item = ZonapropItem()
            item['name'] = casa.css(' a.go-to-posting::text').get()
            item['direction'] = casa.css('span.posting-location.go-to-posting::text').get()
            yield item
```

And this is the way I would like to do it now:

```
        item = ItemLoader(ZonapropItem(), response)
        for casa in response.css('div.posting-card'):
            item.add_css('name', '**SOME CSS**')
            item.add_css('direction','**SOME CSS**')
            yield item.load_item()

Thank you very much!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close to the right answer:

```
for casa in response.css('div.posting-card'):
    loader = ItemLoader(ZonapropItem(), casa)
    loader.add_css('name', 'a.go-to-posting::text')
    loader.add_css('direction','span.posting-location.go-to-posting::text')
    yield loader.load_item()
```

Just instantiate item loader inside of the loop and feed there your `casa` selector.